# np.asarray() gives me one column array where data was multi column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

```
print(X_train_bow.shape) #Output: (897, 2794)
print(type(X_train_bow)) #Output: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

x_train_groups = [X_train_bow[i::5] for i in range(5)]

print(x_train_groups[0].shape) #Output: (299, 2794)
print(type(X_train_bow[0])) #Output: <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

K = 2
train_data = []
test_data = []

for j in range(0, 5):
    if(j != K):
        train_data.extend(x_train_groups[j]) 
test_data.extend(x_train_groups[K])   

print(np.asarray(train_data).shape) #Output: (598,)
print(np.asarray(test_data).shape) #Output: (299,)
```

I'm trying k-fold cross-validation. 
So I have created a method that merges train and test data.
But the problem is that as when I called np.asarray, it returns different shape array that original data shape.
You can see the code. I have also printed output for help.

Comment: `np.asarray` is the wrong tool for combining scipy sparse matrices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a small demo csr matrix:

```
In [212]: M = (sparse.random(12,3,.5, 'csr')*10).astype(int)                    
In [213]: M                                                                     
Out[213]: 
<12x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 18 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [214]: M.A                                                                   
Out[214]: 
array([[3, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 9],
       [0, 6, 0],
       [5, 4, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 0]])
```

Your grouping produces a list of small csr matrices

```
In [216]: alist = [M[i::3] for i in range(3)]                                   
In [217]: alist                                                                 
Out[217]: 
[<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Look at the `K` case:

```
In [218]: data = []                                                             
In [219]: data.extend(alist[2])                                                 
In [220]: data                                                                  
Out[220]: 
[<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

List `extend` adds the elements of the iterable to the list (in a 'flat' sense).  Iteration on sparse matrix (`alist[2]`) yields a bunch of 1 row sparse matrices (still 2d).

We can join them using `sparse.vstack`:

```
In [221]: sparse.vstack(data)                                                   
Out[221]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [222]: sparse.vstack(data).A                                                 
Out[222]: 
array([[1, 0, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 9, 0]])
```

which is just the same as the source of submatrix.

```
In [223]: alist[2]                                                              
Out[223]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [224]: alist[2].A                                                            
Out[224]: 
array([[1, 0, 9],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 9, 0]])
```

Putting that `data` list in an `array` just makes a 1d object dtype array of 1 row sparse matrices. The matrices are just foreign objects to `np.array`.  As general rule don't count on `numpy` functions doing the 'right' thing with sparse matrices.

```
In [225]: np.array(data)                                                        
Out[225]: 
array([<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

Don't just look at shapes.  Check the `dtype`, and examine some elements!

Comment: So basically np.array() gives ndarray type matrix and sparse.vstack() gives csr_matrix matrix. That is the main reason why np.array() shape is not same?

Comment: My test data have one column only, so sparse.vstack(data) will not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: The title says 'multi column'

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `.extend()` and passing in a 2D array. I suspect each of your `train_data` elements has 2794 "columns" and similar for your `test_data`.

Just set these directly to `np.arrays` instead of extending a list.

Something like:

```
K = 1

for j in range(0, 3):
    if(j != K):
        try:
            np.vstack((train_data, x_train_groups[j])) 
        except NameError:
            train_data = x_train_groups[j]
test_data = x_train_groups[K]
```

Comment: K is not fixed. It can be 5. So train data will split data1,data2,data3,data4,data5 then one will be test and other will be train data.

Comment: `np.vstack` does not work with scipy sparse matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement sklearn's [train_test_split()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) on your own, what you can do with your current code is:

```
import numpy as np
train_data = np.array(x_train_groups)[299:, ]  
# shape: (598, 2794) by selecting row 299 onwards
test_data = np.array(x_train_groups)[0:299, ] 
# shape: (299, 2794) by selecting first 299 rows
```

Comment: K is not fixed. It can be 5. So train data will split data1,data2,data3,data4,data5 then one will be test and other will be train data.